# ios iphone delete button (swipe to delete) messes up uitablecellview content

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swipe

I have a problem with a `UITableCellView`. When the delete button shows up, it messes up my table row.

For example:

```
-------------------
blah blah blah blah
-------------------
line 2
-------------------
so on...
-------------------
```

... and after I tried to swipe to delete on line 1,

```
--------------------
blah blah   [delete]
blah ---------------
blah  2
--------------------
so on...
--------------------
```

Not sure how to fix this.

Is there anyway to make `UITableCellView` not shrink when the delete button shows up?

Just to clarify, I have subclassed the `UITableCellView` with an overwritten `layoutSubviews`, but in a very, very simple way.  I just put my labels and calculate size and stuff, very basic.

If you try the same thing on mail app or facebook app, the delete button just go over the content of table cell row.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use the

```
- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];

    if (editing) {
        // EDITING state

        // You can describe animations here

     } else {
        // NORMAL state
     }

}
```

method to describe the changes, in your `UITableViewCell` subclass

Comment: so are you saying that I should reset the width of UITableViewCell contentView if it's editing?

Comment: @Rebecca Alison Yes, that would be something to try. The strange thing is that by default, the content view should shift to the right, with no change to the layout. So I'm guessing, there is a problem with your layoutSubviews method. I normally don't use it, as it can get quite complicated. You can achieve the same result by using three methods: setHighlighted, setSelected, setEditing. Maybe you could rearrange your code, and just describe in each of these methods what you'd like the cell to look like, perhaps within an animation block.

Comment: I found the one way to do what I want,

Comment: - (void)layoutSubviews {
 [super layoutSubviews];
 
 CGRect contentRect = self.contentView.bounds;
 if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation)) {
  contentRect.size.width=480.0f;
 } else {
  contentRect.size.width=320.0f;
 }

Comment: I hate setting a constant value to a width but above works.  I need to find the better way to do it than using a constant value.  My app will look bad if the future iphone changes the resolution!

Comment: @Rebecca Alison You could use the view.frame.size.width & view.frame.size.height properties instead

Comment: Well, if you want to avoid using a constant, you could get the width from `[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width`

Comment: @antalkerekes & @octy,

Do those properly reflect the orientation ?  I don't remember any of those properties do...

I will still have to calculate or pick the correct width based on the orientation, yes?

Comment: @Rebecca Alison Nope, the view's width & height changes with the orientation

Comment: Thanks antalkerekes antalkerekes

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `lineBreakMode` for the label.

```
label.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
```

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work.  my label is like below


  _messageLabel = [[UILabel alloc]init];
  _messageLabel.backgroundColor= _kDefaultBackgroundColor;
  _messageLabel.textColor= _kTextColor;
  _messageLabel.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
  _messageLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:17];
  _messageLabel.numberOfLines=0;
  _messageLabel.lineBreakMode=UILineBreakModeTailTruncation;
  _messageLabel.autoresizingMask= UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

Comment: So you intend it to be a multiline label?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want your cell's subviews to be shrunk in editing mode, try setting the `autoresizingMask` of your cell's subviews to:

```
_messageLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingNone;
```

Comment: that did not work but I found one way to fix my problem.  see my comment above...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps or not since this question is fairly old. However, I had 3 UI elements in my table cell and they were not being handled properly on swipe.

Took me a while to finally figure out that after I changed the "Line Breaks" to "Clip" did everything work properly.

Oh and if you have a text field/label to auto-resizing it will mess up the layout too during the swipe action.